# Exercise 9.1 of Munkres: Axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am trying to solve Exercise 9.1 of Munkres

Exercise 9.1. Define an injective map $f:\mathbb{Z}_{+} \rightarrow X^{w}$, where $X = \{0,1\}$ and $X^{w} = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} X$, without using the choice axiom.

Axiom of choice. Given a collection $\mathcal{A}$ of disjoint nonempty sets, **there exists a set $C$ consisting of exactly one element from each element of $\mathcal{A}$**; that is, a set $C$ such that $C$ is contained in the union of the elements of $\mathcal{A}$, and for each $A \in \mathcal{A}$, the set $C \cap A$ contains a single element.

My attempt in part of choice axiom follows as

$ f(n) = (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3} ,...) $

where $x_{n} = 1$ and others $x_{i} = 0$.

In reference to axiom of choice, I define

$\mathcal{A}  = \{(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},...) \mid x_{j} \in X \} $

So each element of $\mathcal{A}$ is a $w$-tupla. **There is no a set $C$ consisting of exactly one element from each element of $\mathcal{A}$** because I take only those whose nth component is $1$ and others are zero.

Am I right? How can I define this function?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. The question is to define such a function *without* using the axiom of choice. The $f$ you define works, and it's defined explicitly such that you don't need to use the axiom of choice. You're done.

Comment: You seem rather concerned with the choice axiom, when all you are asked to do is to write down a formula for a function $f$, ***ignoring*** the axiom of choice.

Comment: It only has to be injective so consider the binary representation of an element in $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Written backwards?

Comment: @TedShifrin yeah that's the way I would do it.

Comment: @TedShifrin perhaps simpler would the string with $n$ leading ones followed by zeros. Then we don't need positional representation.